# How to fix"Invalid username/password" in Parse

Tags: android, parse-server

I am developing an app which has `signup` and `Login` using parse server,in which i am able to signup but when i try to login it gives me exception

> "Invalid username/password"

This is the code for `signUp` and `LogIn`,when the signUpMode is active the user is signedup on pressing the button alternatively when signUpmode is deactive i.e false the button acts as Login and the user can login but here when i try to login its saying *"Invalid Username/password"*

```
  public void signUp(View view)
        {
            editTextUser =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEdit);
            editTextPass =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWordEdit);

                if(editTextUser.getText().toString().matches("") || editTextPass.getText().toString().matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Username and Password required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(SignupModeActive)
                    {
                        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                        user.setUsername(editTextUser.getText().toString());
                        user.setPassword(editTextUser.getText().toString());
                        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {

                                    if(e == null)
                                    {
                                        Log.i("saveInBackGround","SignUp Success");
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserslistActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }


                            }
                        });


                    }
                    else
                    {
                            ParseUser.logInInBackground(editTextUser.getText().toString(),editTextPass.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                    if(user != null){
                                        Log.i("LogInBackGround","Login Succesfull");
                                        Intent logInintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserslistActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(logInintent);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }



                }
```

Answer (score 0):

//Check your Exception

```
public void signUp(View view)
        {
            mEditTextUser =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEdit);
            mEditTextPass =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWordEdit);

                if(mEditTextUser .getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || editTextPass.getText().toString().trim().length()==0.matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Username and Password required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                 //Check SignupMode is true
   if(SignupModeActive)
                    {
                        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                        user.setUsername(editTextUser.getText().toString());
                        user.setPassword(editTextUser.getText().toString());
                        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {

                                    if(e == null)
                                    {
                                        Log.e("Exception",e.printStackTrace());
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserslistActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }


                            }
                        });


                    }
                    else
                    {
                            ParseUser.logInInBackground(editTextUser.getText().toString(),editTextPass.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                    if(user != null){
                                        Log.i("LogInBackGround","Login Succesfull");
                                        Intent logInintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserslistActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(logInintent);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }



                }
```

Comment: Datatype of Signupmode is boollen which  i initialized it to true and checked if its true it should signUp else LogIn,I am getting exception while LogIn not in Signing

Comment: what was the Exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your codes for login is okay i will say u check whether the details you are feeding is true or not. Maybe their isn't any user with that name or password u feed is wrong .
I am using similar codes and it works fine. my codes are :-

```
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(edtEmail.getText().toString(), 
    edtPassword.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user != null && e == null) {
                                FancyToast.makeText(Login.this, user.get("username") + " is logged in successfully", FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();

                                transitionToWelcomePage();

                            } else {
                                FancyToast.makeText(Login.this, e.getMessage(), FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.ERROR, true).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });
```